# Деньги в юнит-тестах: использование decimal в атрибутах

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, атрибуты, nunit

Есть несколько однотипных юнит-тестов nUnit, в которых проверяется парсинг строки в decimal (именно этот тип рекомендуется в c# для денежных единиц):

```
[Test]
public void Test3()
{
    // Arrange
    var input = "1,234.56";

    // Act
    var result = MoneyParser.Parse(input);

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(1234.56m, result);
}
```

Ну и я соответственно захотел всё это элегантно [упаковать в один метод навесив атрибут TestCase](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestCase-Attribute):

```
[TestCase("1234", 1234m)]
[TestCase("1234.56", 1234.56m)]
[TestCase("1234,56", 1234.56m)]
[TestCase("1 234.56", 1234.56m)]
[TestCase("1 234,56", 1234.56m)]
[TestCase("1,234.56", 1234.56m)]
public void Test(string input, decimal expected)
{
    var result = MoneyParser.Parse(input);

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, result);
}
```

Однако в атрибутах можно использовать только примитивные типы, а код с decimal даже не компилируется — выдаёт ошибку:

> Error CS0182 An attribute argument must be a constant expression,
> typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute
> parameter type

Как можно обойти это препятствие и написать читаемый тест? На ум приходит только вариант задавать на входе expected строкой, преобразовывать внутри теста - и это не нравится ни тем, что легко поломать текст не валидными данными (нет типобезопасности), ни тем, что придётся загромождать код лишними преобразованиями.

Comment: Что если использовать `long` равный  decimal * 10^2 или не 2, а сколько достаточно? Тоже костыль, но лучше чем `string`

Comment: Проблема интересная. Но вызывает сомнение, что разрешено использовать запятую и как разделитель дроби: `1234,56`, и как разделитель тысяч: `1,234.56`. Как бы не возникли потом проблемы из-за этого.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Это моя самописная программа для моих личных домашних финансов и я у неё единственный пользователь. Как ни странно - но вот именно оказалось проще проверить три локали в определённом порядке  и покрывается 100% моих личных потребностей на очень широком спектре русских банков. Я долго шёл к этой формуле, но уже давно её не меняю: ru-RU -> custom ru-RU -> invariant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Поскольку в C# тип `double` может неявно преобразовываться в тип `decimal`, можно просто убрать постфикс `m` для всех `decimal`-значений в атрибуте `TestCase`. Потерь по точности в данном случае не будет (это можно легко проверить, если нужно).

В конечном итоге тест будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
[TestFixture]
public class MoneyParserTests
{
    [TestCase("1234", 1234)]
    [TestCase("1234.56", 1234.56)]
    [TestCase("1234,56", 1234.56)]
    [TestCase("1 234.56", 1234.56)]
    [TestCase("1 234,56", 1234.56)]
    [TestCase("1,234.56", 1234.56)]
    public void Test(string input, decimal expected)
    {
        var result = MoneyParser.Parse(input);

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, result);
    }
}
```

Единственный минус: глядя на эти тесткейсы не скажешь, что метод принимает именно `decimal` параметры.

В других случаях Unit-тест будет обрастать лишними проверками, явными преобразованиями и т.д.

Comment: Неожиданно, но да это работает. Я и забыл про неявную конвертацию, но кажется это самый удачный выход. Заменил m на d, прогнал локально - работает! Спасибо!

Comment: +1. Погрешности все-таки могут быть, но с данной точностью только на больших значениях.

Comment: @defaultlocale я не совсем правильно выразился. Дело в том, что тестирование данного метода не подразумевает то, что метод будет возвращать что-то более точное по количеству знаков после запятой, чем `decimal`. Да, в тест-кейсе можно указать много знаков после запятой, но в конечном итоге сам тест уже будет неправильным с точки зрения семантики. Можно засчитать это как еще один минус данного подхода - возможность допущения ошибки при составлении тест-кейсов.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko Не только после запятой. Например, при конвертации `100000000000000.1` дробная часть потеряется. Но для данного класса проблем, действительно возникнуть не должно, Вы совершенно правы.

Comment: @defaultlocale ой, я совсем забыл, что точность типа с плавающей точкой определяется и целой частью. Стыдно за себя :)

Answer (score 3):

Можно попробовать передать тесты не через атрибуты, с помощью [`TestCaseSource`](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestCaseSource-Attribute). Получится страшненько, но сработает:

```
private static readonly Tuple<string, decimal>[] cases = new[]
{
    Tuple.Create("1234", 1234m),
    Tuple.Create("1234.56", 1234.56m),
    Tuple.Create("1234,56", 1234.56m),
    Tuple.Create("1 234.56", 1234.56m),
    Tuple.Create("1 234,56", 1234.56m),
    Tuple.Create("1,234.56", 1234.56m)
};

private static object[] TestCases()
{
    return cases.Select(t => new object[] { t.Item1, t.Item2 }).ToArray();
}

[TestCaseSource(nameof(TestCases))]
public void Test(string input, decimal expected)
{
    var result = MoneyParser.Parse(input);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, result);
}
```

Преимущество: до определенной степени сохранена типобезопасность при изменении тестов.

Недостатки:

- читаемость упала;
- из-за сигнатуры `object[]` сломать код достаточно легко;
- появился код для преобразования данных.