# Простое тестирование с корректным разделением результатов тестов, когда в параметрах тестового метода находятся объекты

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, xunit

Я тестирую код с помощью **XUnit**. У меня возникла проблема с необходимостью создания объекта внутри параметров(в `[InlineData]`). Я пробовал использовать `[MemberData]`, которая сама по себе является не самым элегантным способом, да и к тому же не работает так, как хотелось бы. Давая несколько наборов параметров я по итогам получаю лишь один результат теста, что, если в действительности тестов, скажем, 10, не очень-то удобно.

Вопрос: Можно ли как-то с параметрами-объектами и нормальным разделением результатов тестов тестировать код? А ещё лучше, если бы вы подсказали другой фреймворк для тестирования, где это выглядит элегантней и нет такой дискриминации объектов в параметрах.

Update Объяснение с кодом: https://pastebin.com/fZN0Fa6z

Comment: Проблема на которую вы жалуетесь не в фреймворке, а в языке. [Тынц1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1222396/213987), [тынц2](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58596064#58596064). В nUnit тоже самое короче. Если я правильно понял вашу проблему - что прямо говоря нелегко, ибо никаких примеров кода в вопросе нет. А суть проблемы - язык требует, чтобы внутри атрибутов были константы и только некоторых строго определённых типов.

Comment: А есть ли обходные пути? И чтобы результаты тестов разделялись? Или вы по итогам предлагаете мне использовать для тестирования подобных методов с объектами в параметрах другой язык, желательно динамически-типизированный по типу Python-а?

Comment: Редакнул. В этом пастебине, конечно, не сам мой код, с которым я в данный момент работаю. Но вряд ли вы захотите разбираться с предметной областью моего проджекта.
В данном примере компиляция не пройдёт по понятным причинам, в аттрибуте InlineData есть не константное выражение(ConsoleText). Как это исправить и в то же время, чтобы по итогам было выдано ДВА результата теста и они не слились в один?

Comment: Ну да, `CS0182 An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type`. Ага, а MemberData это значит как TestCaseSource в nUnit. Ну в общем, да -- я использую именно IEnumerable в отдельном классе и вам рекомендую использовать то же самое. Если кто знает более элегантный способ - будет интересно посмотреть, хотя мне кажется, что пока в языке нет пока возможности красиво обойти подобное ограничение.

Comment: Но вот насчёт сливались в один... Есть разночтение, как показываются тесты с решарпером и через штатные окошки, я прямо сказать привык, но вроде бы у меня никогда на nUnit не сливалось в один, всегда можно было развернуть ветку и посмотреть результаты индивидуального прогона каждого теста.

Comment: Хм, ладно, спасибо. Попробую ещё пошаманить с MemberData, может и не будут сливаться. В крайнем случае для теста нахардкодю тестовый метод.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22093843/5045688 Используйте ClassData или PropertyData

Comment: Выглядит любопытно. Спасибо, завтра попробую

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне помог [другой ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30574322/memberdata-tests-show-up-as-one-test-instead-of-many) на англоязычном StackOverflow от пользователя user1807319.

Решение ни то чтобы красивое и лаконичное, но с учётом безвыходности на что-то более понятное, оно весьма неплохо и, что самое главное, работает, и работает правильно.

Единственно, я немного модифицировал код автора во имя упрощения и безопасности.

Например в `[MemberData("TestData", MemberType = typeof(TestDataProvider))]`, я заменил `"TestData"` на `nameof(TestData)`, чтобы не менять строку, если я изменю имя класса.

Также я убрал любое упоминание testCase, т.к., признаться честно, не понял его предназначения от слова совсем.

[image]